# Signal: contact people, or have people contact me, without revealing phone number?

Tags: privacy, signal-app

Is it possible to use Signal without revealing my phone number to others?

I'm personally using the Signal app on Android, but of course it applies to all versions, desktop and mobile.

With Telegram for example, I can pick a username and then share that username. And people can contact me with just that username. No phone numbers involved. Is something like that possible with Signal as well? Or do I *have* to give my phone number when asking someone to contact me on Signal?

I realize I have to use my phone at least once to register with Signal itself, and setup an account. But once I've done that, I wish to contact other Signal users, or have other Signal users contact me, without revealing my phone number to them.

Comment: Mobile phone questions are off topic on [su].

Comment: @DavidPostill Notice this is about software (Signal), not mobile phones. I did mention I'm using the Android app but Signal is available on all platforms, including Windows, macOS and Linux. And obviously my question applies to all of them (it's a platform-independent issue).

Comment: Then [edit] your question to make it on topic.

Comment: @DavidPostill Done

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** currently do this as Signal was designed at its core to expose phone numbers to contacts. That's your only unique identifier and username.

According to [Does Signal send my number to my contacts?](https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/articles/360007061452-Does-Signal-send-my-number-to-my-contacts-), "Signal does not send your phone number to anyone **unless** you send them a message or make a call to them."

In fact, even when it relates to [Signal and the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR)](https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/articles/360007059412-Signal-and-the-General-Data-Protection-Regulation-GDPR-), the **only** way **not** to expose your number to contacts is "by unregistering your phone number", which means to stop using the app altogether (bringing you back to the original aforementioned "**unless**" part).

...But if it's any consolation, back in middle 2020 [Signal introduced Signal PINs](https://signal.org/blog/signal-pins/) and mentioned "PINs will also help facilitate new features like addressing that isn’t based exclusively on phone numbers, since the system address book will no longer be a viable way to maintain your network of contacts."